# Spacer does not work when I draw custom tab bar with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I was doing some practice in swift ui I made a tab bar like in the picture and I want to move it to the bottom of the screen, but I could not spacer did not work, maybe it is related to the path also I want to give corner radius I am new yet switui thank you in advance for your answers

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        Spacer()
        
        CustomTabBar()
    }
    
}}



struct CustomTabBar: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        Path { path in
            
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20, height: 80))
            
        }
        .cornerRadius(40)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        
        Path { path in
            
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2, y: 200), radius: 50, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(180), clockwise: false)
            
        }.foregroundColor(.white)
        
    }
}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It's related to the Path elements you have. I would do the same with pure SwiftUI Shapes, `Rectangle` and `Circle`. This also eases your work with corner radius.

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            CustomTabBar()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 80)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -50)
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following result:

[image: Result of the code above]